# python: while loop not returning first line (before while loop)

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

I know I'm doing something wrong but I cannot figure out what.
This is a simple program that is supposed to count the number of positive or negative integers and return the value at the end of the program. The very first input line is not being counted to the total.

```
negvar=0
posvar=0
number = input('Enter first number ("q" to exit): ')
while number != 'q':
    number = input('Enter number ("q" to exit): ')
    if str(number) == 'q':
        print()
    elif int(number) < 0:
            negvar = int(negvar) + 1
    elif int(number) > 0:
            posvar = int(posvar) + 1
print('Number of positive values entered:', posvar)
print('Number of negative values entered:', negvar)
```

Any help is much appreciated, as I'm still learning how to properly use while loops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because the first thing you do in the `while` loop is to read another number.  Change the first

```
number = input('Enter first number ("q" to exit): ')
```

to

```
number = None
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not checking the first line to see if it's content, you're immediately ask for a second input in the while loop.

Specifically these lines:

```
number = input('Enter first number ("q" to exit): ')
while number != 'q':
    number = input('Enter number ("q" to exit): ')
```

You could do this instead:

```
negvar=0
posvar=0
number = None
while number != 'q':
    number = input('Enter number ("q" to exit): ')
    if str(number) == 'q':
        print()
    elif int(number) < 0:
            negvar = int(negvar) + 1
    elif int(number) > 0:
            posvar = int(posvar) + 1
print('Number of positive values entered:', posvar)
print('Number of negative values entered:', negvar)
```

Comment: Ok, I new the first line wasn't being checked, when I had tried to include it in the while loop the variable 'number' wasn't determined, I had no idea you could use the command 'None'. Thank you for taking the time to explain!

Answer (score 0):

```
negvar=0
posvar=0
number = input('Enter first number ("q" to exit): ')
while number != 'q':
    if str(number) == 'q':
        print()
    elif int(number) < 0:
            negvar = int(negvar) + 1
    elif int(number) > 0:
            posvar = int(posvar) + 1
    number = input('Enter number ("q" to exit): ')   # Move this here
print('Number of positive values entered:', posvar)
print('Number of negative values entered:', negvar)
```